# Structuring ASP.NET MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to modify a super old ASP.NET MVC project (I didn't write, and I'm still new to ASP.NET MVC).

How do you name and architect/ structure your code?

I'm looking for some real world experience that works and scales.

What I'm hoping is making the code easier to maintain, and adding unit tests. Right now, some of the controllers are more than 2000 lines of codes, and I'm hoping to split the code into many smaller parts, to help with readability, reuse of functions and better testability
What do you do?

Do you have the function and move the business code to different file(s)

If so, do you have a classlib project?

MyMainProject (ASP.NET MVC)

```
- Controllers
  - EmailController
    - SendEmail(){} (uses MyMainProject.<name> -> Email -> Email -> SendEmail() implementation of sendmail?)
- Models
- Views 
- AppCode

MyMainProject.<name>? (Classlib project)
- Email (folder) * Folder and class same name?
  - Email (class) *
    - SendEmail() (function)

MyMainProject.UnitTests

- ControllersTests
  - EmailControllerTests
    - SendEmailTest.cs
      - (Unit test 1 etc)
```

And do you have two unit test projects - one for the main project and one for the classlib project (if I should use a classlib project)?

If I only need one unit test project, how do you structure it?

Something like this?

```
MyMainProject.UnitTests (name ok?)

- MyMainProject
  - ControllersTests
    - EmailControllerTests
      - SendEmailTest.cs
        - (Unit test 1 etc)

- MyMainProject.<name>? (Classlib project, and what do you call <name>)
- Email (folder) * Folder and class same name?
  - Email (class) *
    - SendEmail() (function)

- MyMainProject.<name>? (Do you have more classlib than one, if you have one?)
```

(Or is this something that should be posted under clean-code tag?)

Comment: There are a lot of questions here, more than we would reasonably expect to be able to answer in a single question. I would start by learning the SOLID principles which will help you refactor the code in to smaller more maintainable chunks. I wouldn't worry too much at this stage about how to structure things, you can do that later. All of your questions are really too opinionated too.

Comment: @phuzi You are right, I need to learn the solid, it seems the S part, is going to help a lot with the read and testability. So I will get started reading/ learning the solid principle, thanks :)

Comment: Your question is going to attract a lot of personal opinions IMO. Here's mine: * Make controllers as lean as possible. They should only be handling things like authentication and validation. * Move your business logic into separate classes and _loosely_ couple them to the controllers by creating relevant interfaces and using DI to get these from controllers. * Move business logic into a separate classlib. * Definitely create the unit tests for the business logic classes, but think twice if you'd need any for controllers - there should be literally nothing to test there.